# Custom chapter name in The Legrand Orange Book

Tags: chapters, books, book-design, legrandorangebook

I am using the Legrand Orange Book available [available_here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) I want to modify the chapter so that they display as follows

[image]

I want the chapter to have numbers starting with the word Unit then the number comes followed by the title. Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines after `\documentclass[...]{LegrandOrangeBook}`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\outputchaptertitle}{#1.}{Unit #1:}{}{}
```

[image: a]